# Visual Studio 2022 (17.4.2) MAUI not working

Tags: macos, maui, platform

I installed Visual Studio 2022 on Mac M1 and was trying to write a MAUI app. But when I create a template project and try to build it, I keep getting the below errors:
[image]

[image]

I tried a lot of things including reinstalling Visual Studio and dotnet frameworks, nothing worked!

Any clues as to what should be done here?

Comment: Please don't post error messages (or code) as text: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You followed [installation instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/installation?tabs=vsmac&view=net-maui-7.0)? You included (checkmarked) all the required **workloads**?

Comment: Yes. I can even see all the workloads installed when I list them.

Comment: Did this error happen before? Have you tried restart your mac?

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing the maui-android and maui-ios workloads manually. You could refer to [dotnet workload install commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-workload-install#examples).

In addition, you could check the csproj file to see if there is the TargetFrameworks element :

```
<TargetFrameworks>net6.0-android;net6.0-ios;net6.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
```

For more info, you could refer to [Build your first app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/first-app?tabs=vsmac&pivots=devices-android&view=net-maui-7.0).

Hope it works for you.